# Weblogic server getting crashed

Tags: java-8, weblogic, sap-commerce-cloud

Below error is occurring in logs. Application was running fine until last month and it started occurring all of sudden without any changes. I tried to find more about this and I found, this happens due to **modification of zip/jar which is in use** specially in Linux(Window does not allow modification). It is suggested to find the problematic code/scenarios, which I could not identify so far as this happens only in production. It is also suggested to Run JDKs with -Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true system property. Which will disable memory mapping and the application will fail instead with a "file corrupted" type ZipException. This property also has some performance impact. Could you please help how can find the problematic code? How likely this property can help in resolving the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Below are the errors shown :

```
1..

# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment: 
# 
# SIGBUS (0x7) at pc=0x00007fe3fca8053e, pid=6120, tid=140605725304576 
# 
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_60-b27) (build 1.8.0_60-b27) 
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.60-b23 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops) 
# Problematic frame: 
# C [libc.so.6+0x14f53e] __memmove_ssse3_back+0x23de 
# 
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again 
2.
# 
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment: 
# 
# SIGBUS (0x7) at pc=0x00007f9137df6802, pid=13359, tid=140250685896448 
# 
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_60-b27) (build 1.8.0_60-b27) 
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.60-b23 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops) 
# Problematic frame: 
# C [libzip.so+0x11802] newEntry+0x62 
# 
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
```

Comment: Which version of hybris do you use?

Comment: We are using 5.7 version of Hybris.